# Manga where a man goes to learn all about beast men culture

Tags: story-identification, manga

A think he was some kinda scientist or researcher but his professor who’s be researching beast men for a long time is retiring or something and also married one of the beast men he gives the mc a book of what he knows about the beast men and the mc sets out with the professors half beast daughter.
It’s a very sweet manga and the really dive into how the beast men think and talk and interact with each other,the main things I remember is that he trades with a octopus by grabbing its arm and the little beast girl is small with black hair and tail, at one point they also try to repair a house to stay in while there’s a storm and other beast men will come in and during the night one of the beast men die.I’ve been dying to find this it was so good but nothing I search up gets any decent results I really want to read it again

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Was it in colour?

Comment: It was about like two years ago I think it was not in colour but I can’t remember where I read it